# EditText always has same size on device but not on emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout

I do have a problem with EditTexts in a landscape view. Somehow they always display in the same size on my device! I do have the same device as an emulator and there it is ok? Does anyone have an idea why this is??

I also tried to remove everything except the EditText and still it is displayed like this.

I also removed all the arguments (size, etc.) from the EditText and still it is displayed in the same size on the device and on the emulator it is just a small box.

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:weightSum="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="295dp" android:background="@drawable/lens_calc_back" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="210dp">
    <TableRow>
        <TableLayout>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="@string/obj_size" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="45dp" android:layout_width="60dp"></TextView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <EditText android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:minWidth="70dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:id="@+id/eTobj_size" android:maxLength="5" android:layout_height="40dp" android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:text="45.0" android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"></EditText>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <TableLayout>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="@string/focal_length" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></TextView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <EditText android:id="@+id/eTfocal_length" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:minWidth="70dp" android:maxLength="5" android:layout_height="40dp" android:text="25.0" android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"></EditText>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/iVcamera" android:src="@drawable/s_vit" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"></ImageView>        
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <EditText android:inputType="number" android:text="800" android:id="@+id/eTpixels" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:minWidth="70dp" android:layout_marginLeft="320dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" android:maxLength="4"></EditText>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="@string/number_pixels" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            </TableRow>         
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="45dp">  
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="@string/distance" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></TextView>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/eTdistance" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:minWidth="70dp" android:maxLength="5" android:layout_height="40dp" android:text="100.4" android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"></EditText>
    </TableRow> 
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:background="#FF606060" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bS_vit"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
            android:text="@string/s_ser"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="140dp">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bQ_vit"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
            android:text="@string/q_ser"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="140dp">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bTri"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
            android:text="@string/tri"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_width="140dp">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks in the emulator:

[image]

And like this on the device:

[image]

Comment: First of all make it sure that your emulator density/resolution and device density/resolution is same or not.

Comment: No real solution to your problem, but why don't you use a RelativeLayout. I think that a RL will make it much easier to place the elements on the screen.

Comment: @Hitendra: both have the same resolution and density. And also it does not make any sense to me that the size of the EditText does not change at all on the device! :-(

Comment: @banzai86: I will have to look into RelativeLayout, I am not familiar with this yet. But as you say, the Layout type does not make any difference regarding the size of an EditText...

Comment: indeed, but you can easier handle the dimensions of each element if they don't have to fit in a table row/column

Answer (score 0):

You could try supplying some layout parameters for your inner `TableLayouts`.

As you haven't supplied any layout parameters, they probably just use "standard" layout parameters which aren't guaranteed to support the layout you're trying to build.